# How to Access Camera in Android 6.0 Marshmallow?

Tags: android, camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am to new to Android 6.0 Coding Please Provide a solutions For the Below Code:

When i provide Run Time Permissions like `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it shows an Exception like

> **java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.motorola.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyAppNew%20File%20Upload/IMG_20160401_110234.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{ed96564 26955:com.social.nocializer/u0a259} (pid=26955, uid=10259) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA**

Either `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE` Run Time Permissions are not working...

Note: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Works For When Opening Gallery

Comment: Please check it and implement.
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: thanks dude it provides the details concept about run time permission in android 6.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to manage run time permission for this, Because whichever permissions you have defined in AndroidManifest will not be automatically granted. So like below method you can check whether you permission is approved or not

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
            MY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Here, MY_REQUEST_CODE is a static constant that you can define, which will be used again for the requestPermission dialog callback. Now, You will need a callback for the dialog result:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST__CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Now user should be able to use camera
        }
        else {
            // Your app will not have this permission. Turn off all functions 
            // that require this permission or it will force close like your 
            // original question
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Dude.... Its Works Perfectly without any Error... ThankYou So Much......

Comment: @Ronak Joshi.. Thanks. You saved my day

Comment: @Ronak Joshi How can i override onRequestPermissionResult in my activity???

Comment: You can easily override as you overriding others methods. But it only will call if the API level is greater than 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow). @KJEjava48

Comment: @KJEjava48 In order to override `onRequestPermissionResult()` in Android Studio press **CTRL+O** (or **Alt+Insert -> Override Methods...**) and perform a double click on `onRequestPermissionResult()`.

Answer (score 9):

@Ronak Solution worked for me but with a few following changes, As we need to check on only those devices which are above Android M.

```
 if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                5);
                    }
                }
```

And override the following method using crl+o copying, pasting would might result in an error :D

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 5) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Now user should be able to use camera
            }
            else {
                // Your app will not have this permission. Turn off all functions
                // that require this permission or it will force close like your
                // original question
            }
    }
```