# My app crash as soon as I select a image?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-camera, android-gallery

I am completely new to Android Studio and I have been trying to make an app that scans using the (:scanLibrary) given by this link and followed the instructions given here https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo. There is no compilation error but only some runtime error. Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?

This is my code

```
 package com.mukesh.android.digiwrite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity;
import com.scanlibrary.ScanConstants;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "tag" ;
private Button click;
private Button gallery;
public final int request_Code = 99;
public ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "part2");
    click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    gallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, ScanConstants.OPEN_MEDIA);
            startActivityForResult(intent, request_Code);
            Log.d(TAG, "part4");
        }
    });


   /* click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, ScanConstants.OPEN_CAMERA);
            startActivityForResult(intent, request_Code);
        }
    });*/

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "part5");
    if (requestCode == request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getExtras().getParcelable(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "part6");
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


}
```

I have also given the required read and write permission in the manifest file as shown:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mukesh.android.digiwrite">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

But still the app keeps getting closed as soon as I click on the gallery button and select an image. I tried running it on android sdk23.

Edit 1

This is the error I am getting.

```
 06-09 18:23:18.899 25835-25835/com.mukesh.android.digiwrite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.mukesh.android.digiwrite, PID: 25835
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mukesh.android.digiwrite/com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.motorola.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/scanSample/IMG_20170609_182318.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{1e3886 25835:com.mukesh.android.digiwrite/u0a131} (pid=25835, uid=10131) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.motorola.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/scanSample/IMG_20170609_182318.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{1e3886 25835:com.mukesh.android.digiwrite/u0a131} (pid=25835, uid=10131) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2679)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1693)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4570)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4556)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:6652)
                                                                              at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1112)
                                                                              at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1101)
                                                                              at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.openCamera(PickImageFragment.java:129)
                                                                              at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.handleIntentPreference(PickImageFragment.java:77)
                                                                              at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.init(PickImageFragment.java:58)
                                                                              at com.scanlibrary.PickImageFragment.onCreateView(PickImageFragment.java:48)
                                                                              at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                              at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1537)
                                                                              at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6275)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
     06-09 18:23:20.589 26141-26153/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
     06-09 18:23:22.793 26217-26217/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
     06-09 18:23:22.794 26217-26217/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
```

My Xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mukesh.android.digiwrite.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:text="@string/button2" />

</LinearLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried running it on android sdk 19 and it works fine. But in android sdk 23,24, 25 it isn't working.

Thank you

Comment: Post your logcat error message please :)

Comment: @Bumblebee9898 Please Upload Your xml and Error Logcat Please Then Help You Betterly.

Comment: So, is it crashing after button click or image selection?

Comment: @MacLeanSochor and @ Ashish Shahi ... I updated my error message.

Comment: @ChristianAscone it is crashing after image selection from gallary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349130/how-to-access-camera-in-android-6-0-marshmallow here it is basically you need to add permissions in manifest and above lollipop devices you need to ask for runtime permissions.