# Attempting to open camera causes my app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I have a Button object called takeNewPic that I want to open the camera and then be able to take a picture. However, every time I attempt to do so my app crashes.

```
 takeNewPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConfigTakeNewPic);
 takeNewPic.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in my onClick method I called takePicture(), which looks like this:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

In the manifest I have the lines

```
 <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, I run into a null pointer exception with an error that reads

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { 
act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE 
cmp=com.motorola.cameraone/com.motorola.camera.Camera } from 
ProcessRecord{dffcd00 28714:com.example.bill.hw2/u0a142} (pid=28714, 
uid=10142) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

Comment: I know there are very similiar questions on StackOverflow and I tried doing what they suggested but I kept getting the error

Comment: NPE? How about `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial`

Comment: *I tried doing what they suggested* and what was that?

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant @ScaryWombat

Comment: The suggestions mainly revolved around people not including the permissions in the manifest

Comment: You need to provide runtime persmission, Since the new runtime permission model is introduced in Android 6.0,

Answer (score 1):

Have you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349130/how-to-access-camera-in-android-6-0-marshmallow)?

You need to manage the runtime permission as described in the link above.

Comment: I hadn't seen that link yet, no, but looking at it I am still confused.  I can see that I am still lacking permissions needed open and use the camera, but I am not sure where the methods provided in the link above would be added to my code.  "onRequestPermissionResult" is not used elsewhere in their code (at least not as far as I can see) and I'm not sure where I would place the initial if structure either. I am very new to Android Studios.

Comment: You need to check this before you access the camera. Check out google's official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java

Answer (score 0):

You have to request permission from the phone itself. Either manually go to app settings and allow app to use camera or use this:

```
requestPermissions(permissionReq, RECORD_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);
```